# Manage Package Upgrade taking components of another app

Tags: salesforce, package

I am Releasing new upgrade for manage package but in component list (those are going to release) containing objects/Apex classes/Pages from another app also. The another app which included in  release is not referred anywhere, I have checked dependencies also but still it taking all components from another app and I cannot even remove that.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I were you I'd try uninstalling that other app.  That will cause the system to do a full dependency check and tell you what exactly is referring to the other package.

Comment: This is very risky. We are using second application also and we have live data in application.

Comment: Well I'm not suggesting that you actually uninstall the second app, just that you begin the process so that the dependency checker tells you what's dependent on it.  Also: you really shouldn't have live data in the org from which you distribute a managed package.  A best practice is to have an org devoted to each managed package with nothing else in it.

Comment: Able to resolve issue. One of the permission set was causing issue.